# Why is this counter increasing in this way and not one by one in this divide and conquer algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I was reading an algorithm solution to the following problem:

> This file contains all of the 100,000 integers between 1 and 100,000 (inclusive) in some order, with no integer repeated.
>   Your task is to compute the number of inversions in the file given, where the ith row of the file indicates the ith entry of an array.
>   Because of the large size of this array, you should implement the fast divide-and-conquer algorithm covered in the video lectures.
>   The numeric answer for the given input file should be typed in the space below.

So the problem gives you the file, but here is the solution:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100000

using namespace std;

long long splitInv(long *arr, long l, long u)
{
     long *tarr = new long[u-l+2];
     long i=l, j=(u-l)/2+l+1, k;
     long long count=0;
     for(k=1; (k<=u-l+1) && (i<=(u-l)/2+l) && (j<=u); k++)
     {
              if(arr[i]<arr[j]) tarr[k]=arr[i++];
              else
              {
                  tarr[k]=arr[j++];
                  count=count+((u-l)/2+l-i+1);
              }
     }
     for(; k<=u-l+1 && i<=(u-l)/2+l; k++) tarr[k]=arr[i++];
     for(; k<=u-l+1 && j<=u; k++) tarr[k]=arr[j++];
     for(k=1, i=l ; k<=u-l+1 && i<=u; k++, i++) arr[i]=tarr[k];
     delete tarr;
     return count;
}

long long numInv(long *arr, long l, long u)
{
     if(u<=l) return 0;
     return numInv(arr, l, (u-l)/2+l) + numInv(arr, (u-l)/2+l+1, u) + splitInv(arr, l, u);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long *arr=new long[SIZE+1];
    char a[10];
    FILE *f=fopen("IntegerArray.txt","r");
    for(long i=1; i<=SIZE; i++)
    {
            fgets(a,10,f);
            arr[i]=atol(a);
    }
    fclose(f);
    cout<<"Number of Inversions: "<<numInv(arr,1,SIZE)<<endl;
    delete arr;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So, I was wonder why the counter is increasing by the following way and not one by one, because it's just counting the number of inversions:

```
count=count+((u-l)/2+l-i+1);
```

So, for me it should be:

```
count=count+1;
```

Comment: As you know it is using divide and conquer algorithm it need to ignore the first half if your if condition is not true, so it has to offset your array as shown in your program and not like as you assume

Comment: @quetzalcoatl  I will make it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you know it is using divide and conquer algorithm it need to ignore the first half if your if condition is not true, so it has to offset your array as shown in your program and not like as you assume .